# Symmetry property for Laguerre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

The classic type of orthogonal polynomials $H_n(x)$, $P_n(x)$, $T_n(x)$ and $U_n(x)$ have symmetry property.
Does the Laguerre polynomials $L_n(x)$ also has symmetry property?

$L_n(-x)=L_n(x)$ and $L_n(-x)=-L_n(x)$

Pls help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From glancing at the [first few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomial#The_first_few_polynomials), the answer is clearly **no**.  In particular, $L_1(x) = -x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can see by writing even the first two or three Laguerre polynomials. But we shouldn't expect them to be since they form an orthogonal family on $[0,\infty)$ (with respect to the weight function $e^{-x}$), rather than a symmetric interval about the origin.

Comment: oh. Thanks for answering my question. :)

Comment: Did my post answer your question? If so, consider [accepting it](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and/or upvoting it as this is good form and will encourage others to answer your future questions.

Comment: Yes sir. you definitely answered it. You said No,the Laguerre polynomials has no symmetry property.